# Как привязать progressbar?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть класс Test и в нем есть коллекция, прогресс обработки которой нужно отслеживать.

Сделал как ниже, но то и дело появляется исключение "Тип значения по умолчанию не совпадает с типом свойства".

Code-behind:

```
    public static DependencyProperty ProgressProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("Progress", typeof(double), typeof(Test),  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)));
    public static DependencyProperty MaxProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Max", typeof(double), typeof(Test), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)));
    public static DependencyProperty MinProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Min", typeof(double), typeof(Test), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)));
```

Xaml разметка выглядит следующим образом:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pbMain" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="20" 
             Maximum="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Test.MaxProperty}}" 
             Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Test.ProgressProperty}, Mode=OneWay}"
             Minimum="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Test.MinProperty}}" />
```

Я правильно понимаю, что привязка должна делаться через свойства зависимости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно вы объявляете Dependency Property, без геттера и сеттера.

Ну и привязываться нужно к `Max`, а не к `MaxProperty`.

Если класс `Test` является вашим `DataContext`'ом, попробуйте так:

```
Maximum="{Binding Max}"
```

Если класс `Test` является вашим контролом, в котором находится XAML-разметка (например, окном), делайте так:

```
Maximum="{Binding Max, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```